# popViewController throwing "deallocated while key value observers were still registered" error

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, swift5

I'm having problems with deallocating an observable, even using a disposedBag. **It only occurs in iOS 10.**

I have to associate a TextField (SwiftMaskField) value to a variable at viewModel, so I'm doing:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, Storyboarded {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtField: SwiftMaskField!

    var viewModel: BaseViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bindUI()
    }

    private func bindUI() {
        txtField.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: viewModel.myString).disposed(by: viewModel.bag)

        viewModel.showLoading.asObservable().skip(1).subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
            self.showLoading()
        }).disposed(by: viewModel.bag)
    }

    ...
}
```

```
class BaseViewModel {
    var showLoading = BehaviorRelay<Void>(value: ())
    var myString = BehaviorRelay<String>(value:"")

    let bag = DisposeBag()

    func foo() {
        showLoading.accept(())
    }

    func foo2() {
        print(myString.value)
    }

    ...
}
```

#### When I do a ***popViewController***, my app crashes with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance
>   0x7fbaafe45a20 of class SwiftMaskText.SwiftMaskField was deallocated
>   while key value observers were still registered with it. Current
>   observation info:  (
>    Context: 0x0,
>   Property: 0x6000002596e0> )'
>
> ---

It only occurs in iOS 10 (haven't tested previous versions), further versions don't crash.

Also, I'm using RxSwift 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your bag has to be above your view in the class hierarchy. Try this:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, Storyboarded {

    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    @IBOutlet weak var txtField: SwiftMaskField!

    var viewModel: BaseViewModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bindUI()
    }

    private func bindUI() {
        txtField.rx.text.orEmpty.bind(to: viewModel.myString).disposed(by: bag)

        viewModel.showLoading.asObservable().skip(1).subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
            self.showLoading()
        }).disposed(by: bag)
    }

    ...
}
```

That will likely fix it, let me know if it doesn't.

Also, your view model shouldn't need a dispose bag, if it does you are probably doing something wrong in there.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it didn't work. The problem is probably with SwiftMaskField, because I've tested changing it to UITextField and there was no crash. I'll have to possibly make my own mask.